# React complex tree in Controlled Environment drag and drop bugs

Tags: reactjs

with my team mates we are trying to implement a tree in React using react-complex-tree. We are using the controlled Environment because we want to make the user able to add and remove items. We are also implementing the Drag and drop mechanism, we filled the onDrop event and the "putting an item inside another" mechanism works. If we don't expand any Item also the reordering mechanism works, buf if we expand some Items and we try to move some child became all broken! The "target" element is wrong and in some cases (with the elements on bottom of the tree) also the "item" array is wrong!!! On "bestofreactjs.com" there is the issue #15, and seems to be similar. We are in trouble, this problems is making lose a big amount of time! How can we fix it ? Thanks all for the answers.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducing example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue so we are able to help.

Comment: better open an issue on their repo and give reproducible example to them

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava I already did, but they didn't answer my question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.